# How to merge array values on the basis of repetive values?

Tags: php

I have this array in my code

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Roof setting
        [1] => [2013-04-22,7]
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Garbage Collection
        [1] => [2013-04-22,22]
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales Payout
        [1] => [2013-04-22,10]
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales Payout
        [1] => [2013-04-25,10]
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales Payout
        [1] => [2013-04-25,10]
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Fix cable car2
        [1] => [2013-04-24,77.79]
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => Fix cable car2
        [1] => [2013-04-25,77.79]
    )

)
```

Now I want to get this array in the form that for each repeating label it shows the label only one time and repetive dates along those labels multiple times.The result should look like this

```
Array
(
    'label': => Roof setting
        (

        'data:' => [2013-04-22,7]
    ),

   'label' => Garbage Collection
    (

        'data': => [2013-04-22,22]
    )

'label' => Sales Payout
    (

       'data:' => [[2013-04-22,10],[2013-04-25,10],[2013-04-25,10]]
    )



   'label' =>Fix cable car2
    (
       'data' => [[2013-04-24,77.79[,2013-04-25,77.79]]
        [1] => [2013-04-24,77.79[
    )
)
```

Comment: see http://whathaveyoutried.com for insights about HOW to ask questions. You won't get any help with your current question!

Comment: I think you just need a foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

You could prolly get the result you want with something like this:

```
foreach($array as $arr)
    $out[$arr[0]][] = $arr[1];
```

Where $array is your array containing the data.

Comment: can you please elobrate it,,i am not getting what are you saying

Comment: What the code above does, is loop trough the array containing your data. It then creates a new array, $out, it makes the first value from your original array, a key in the new array, and then adds the following dates in an array under the same key.

Try run the foreach loop above, and then do a print_r($out) to see the structure of the new array. Might help understand what it does.

Comment: Array
(
    [Roof setting] => Array
        (
            [0] => [2013-04-22,7]
        )

    [Garbage Collection] => Array
        (
            [0] => [2013-04-22,22]
        )

    [Sales Payout] => Array
        (
            [0] => [2013-04-25,10]
        )

    [Fix cable car2] => Array
        (
            [0] => [2013-04-25,77.79]
        )

)......it is giving follwoing output not matching what i want